# How can I swap odd-array?

Tags: arrays, swift, swap

How can I swap odd-array? index out of range every time the array is odd. How can I have a checker if the last array is odd it will not do the swap?

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

if list.count > 0 {
    for index in 2..<list.count {
        if index % 2 == 0 {
            list.swapAt(index, index + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the swap until the `list.count - 1`, so it won't go out of the list range.

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

if list.count > 0 {
    for index in stride(from: 2, to: list.count - 1, by: 2){
         list.swapAt(index,index+1)
    }
}
```

Comment: And I would replace the `for` and the 2nd `if` with just `for index in stride(from: 2, to: list.count - 1, by: 2)`.

Comment: guess that the `by:2` is not even necessary. it was being used just to prevent the `out of range` error.

Comment: I believe the 2nd `if` is used to swap the evens with the odds. The result will be `1,2,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,11`. For some reason the OP chose not to swap the first pair.

Answer (score 0):

Think simple. Maximum index is `list.count-1` and the index of the first of a pair to swap must be less than that. Now just use a `while`:

```
var index = 0
while index < list.count-1
{
   list.swapAt(index, index+1) // swap current pair
   index += 2                  // increment by 2 to get to next pair
}
```